# Javascript validation on paging in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

The following code worked as expected, however on the paging click, it still execute and display message "Please select a record first, then press this button". Is there anyway to prevent this unless the export button click. Thank you

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Product").on("click",function(){
                var $exportLink = $('#export');
                var href = $exportLink.attr('href');
                var grid = $('#Product').data('kendoGrid');   //get a reference to the grid data 
                var record = grid.dataItem(grid.select()); //get a reference to the currently selected row
                if(record !=null)
                {
                    href = href.replace(/refId=([^&]*)/, 'refId='+record.ID);
                    $exportLink.attr('href', href);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Please select a record first, then press this button")
                    return false;
                }

            });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a click handler as `$("#Product").on("click",function(){...})` you are actually defining it for any click on `#Product` not just on you `Export` button. You should define the `on` for the `button` and not for the `grid`